# Ubuntu 22.04 icon in dock 'unknown'

Tags: 22.04, dock

Recenty upgraded to 22.04.
Dock has an icon that looks like a white gear on a grey background.
I cannot right-click 'remove from favorites'.
It also has a red dot at the bottom (indicating it is running).

I'd like to remove the icon from the dock, but I can't find a way to do this.

Comment: Some leftover. You cannot right-click then close the program? You do not see its title in the to bar when clicking the icon (to bring it to the front)?

Comment: I cannot right-click and close the program.  I do not see its title bar when clicking the icon to bring it to the front.  I agree 100% it is a leftover or remnant of my 20.04 installation.  I just want to get rid of it. ;-)